# basic shell commands extremely slow on Git-Bash, sh.exe but fine on Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, git-bash

When I run basic commands like `pwd` and `cd` the command *itself* executes fast but the console hangs for 1 second before allowing me to execute another command.

I got the latest Git Bash portable and tried

- 32- and 64-bit
- Run as admin
- `sh.exe` instead of `git-bash.exe` (and Run as admin)

But `Cygwin` does not have this problem.
In `Cygwin`, running `pwd` from the same directory as any Git Bash variant results in equally fast *command* completion but also there is no console hanging.

My Windows is: `Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044`

I have [nVidia Quadro P3000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762587/4784683)

**UPDATE from comments below**:
It appears to be an issue with my Git installation but I chose the defaults so I don't know what it could be.
When I execute `PS1='$ '` in Git-Bash, I do not have the the 1-second pause after each command is executed.

**UPDATE from comments below**

```
$ echo ${PS1@A}
declare -x PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$ '
```

I did not change anything.
I download a version of portable [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases?page=7), launch as admin and type `ls`, `pwd`, etc.

I went back to [2.24](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.24.0.windows.1) but same behavior.

I'm also going to try it on my personal PC since it could be my corporate antivirus that's causing this.

**UPDATE**

The issue is `__git_ps1` and there's [an open issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192014/git-ps1-extremely-slow-in-kernel-tree)

Comment: If your git-bash builds the prompt in bash shell, double check if it's working fine.

Comment: @Philippe I do not understand your comment.

Comment: git-bash tries to get current git branch and shows it on the prompt. Can you just do `PS1='$ '` to see if it improves ?

Comment: @Philippe it improved a lot. `pwd` and other commands are now as fast as on `Cygwin`.

Comment: @Philippe the problem is not only in a Git directory. Ignoring your temporary fix, `pwd` was slow in any directory when I was in `Git-Bash`

Comment: I know. Git-Bash tries to detect if current directory is a git directory even though it's not. So now you need to troubleshoot why Git-Bash has difficulty to do that.

Comment: @Philippe you'd think a bug this obvious would be fixed by now.

Comment: It may not be a bug, could be related to your environment, particularly your git settings.

Comment: We can't see your original value of `PS1`. Quite obviously you have configured a prompt command which does something which takes time, but we can't help you further.

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2879

Comment: Please open a new console, hit `declare -p PS1` and/or `echo ${PS1@A}`, then add the result to your question.

Comment: From your description, it looks that the fancy things you do inside your `PS1` take more time in git-bash than in Cygwin bash. Did you use the same `PS1` setting in Cygwin bash? If not, you are comparing apple and pears.

Comment: You are invoking `__git_ps1` from your PS1: Try to run the command manually in both environments. I suspect it takes much longer under Cygwin.

Comment: @user1934428 `__git_ps1` doesn't work in Cygwin

Comment: Why are you using it then?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm using Git-Bash out of the box.

Comment: Did you already trace the execution of this command, to see where it takes most time?

Comment: @user1934428 how do I trace the execution of `__git_ps1` in Windows?

Comment: The issue is `__git_ps1` and there's [an open issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192014/git-ps1-extremely-slow-in-kernel-tree)

Comment: You type on the command line `set -x; __git_ps1; set +x`.

Comment: @Bob: This assumes that __git_ps1 is a **function** (which I believe to be the case). I would check this before with `type __git_ps1`. If it is a shell script, you would use a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `__git_ps1` is the culprit.

As a test, put following code in `/tmp/experiment.sh`

```
if  [[ "$(type -t __git_ps1)" == 'function' ]]; then
  cd(){
    builtin cd "$@"
    __GIT_PS1=$('__git_ps1') # Calling original __git_ps1, only when changing directory.
  }
  __git_ps1_stub(){
    echo "$__GIT_PS1" # Now $PS1 will do this echo, instead of calling __git_ps1
  }
  alias __git_ps1=__git_ps1_stub # __git_ps1_stub will be called in $PS1
  cd . # Initialize $__GIT_PS1 for the first time.
fi
```

Then start a git-bash terminal, and run `source /tmp/experiment.sh`

If situation improves, you can put the code in ~/.bashrc

You'll need to change other commands (like pushd, popd, etc) if you use them to change directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to simplify your PATH when testing your Git bash.
In a CMD, type

```
set "GH=C:\Program Files\Git"
set "PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Then try again and type `bash` to enter a shell session.

By default, I get:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
```

And it is quite fast.
(Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044.1586, git version 2.35.1.windows.2)

Comment: I updated my question with the value of `PS1`; I don't touch it. It's probably an issue with antivirus.

Comment: @Bob Was it faster with the simplified PATH?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to slow resolution of computer network names.  Since the computer name is involved in the command line.  I advise you to add yourhostname and localhost to etc/hostname.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was corrupt page file. Try clearing Windows page file and rebooting. Page file was constantly causing my git bash to hang for 20 seconds with just carriage returns. I've re-enabled page file several times and eventually it happens again. Clearing page file fixed it every time.
I turn page file completely off now and git bash is screaming fast.