# when using git for windows, git bash could not work?

Tags: git, msysgit

[image: problem when using git1.8 for windows]

I install git-1.8 in windows7, but encounter this problem(nearly every time when I use 'git config' or some else), can someone tell why and how to fix?

Comment: your issue seems related to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851611/git-sh-exe-process-forking-issue-on-windows-xp-slow

Comment: um...it's ok now, i installed github in my pc before, after i uninstalled it and then install msysgit, it works! it seems conflict with github's gitshell, why? curious......@Irineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both msysgit and GitHub for Windows, but I would recommend using the portable version of msysgit in order to avoid any conflict in the Windows registry.

Also, `WFSO` is a [Windows semaphore](https://github.com/bjoernknafla/amp/issues/6#issuecomment-373774) (`WaitForSingleObject`), illustrated in [issue 457](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457) for instance. It is a symptome of a resource deadlock, resource which would be use by both bash (G4W and msysgit)

> With the addition of the multiplexing there is a second thread reading from the socket before the client is spawned and it continues until after all the data from the child is supposed to be written.  This causes a deadlock.

I try not use them at the same time.