# Are there an issues with running msysGit and GitHub for Windows on the same machine?

Tags: git, msysgit, github-for-windows

I have been searching but not finding an answer, are there any issues or conflicts running msysGit and GitHub for Windows on the same machine? On my local pc I already have GitHub for Windows installed and I need to install [msysGit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.4-preview20140929) to use with Atlassian Stash but if there are conflicts then I will remove GH4W.  I can't find a good answer but I did find this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681368/when-using-git-for-windows-git-bash-could-not-work) question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub for Windows (GH4W) runs in a sandboxed environment so there are no problems in installing GH4W and msysGit on the same system.

From [haacked.com](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx/):

> GH4W is a sandboxed installation of Git and the GitHub application
>   that takes care of all that configuration. Please note, it will not
>   mess with your existing Git environment if you have one.

When you install msysGit you get to choose between three options for the `PATH` environment, see image.

[image: msysGit PATH options]

I do recommend to pick one of the safe options while installing msysGit.
I've been using both  GH4W and msysGit (installed with the "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt" option) on the same system for quite some time and never had any problems.