# Errors running sh.exe in msysgit in windows XP

Tags: sh, msysgit

I'm having difficulties with msysgit in a windowXP 32 bit environment I would really appreciate some help with.  In actual fact, I'm using SmartGit and love the program.  However it fails to run both Save Stash and Clean Up.  As I thought the problem was with SmartGit, I approached the developers for help. However, it turns out the problem with with msysgit.
The SmartGit I have uses msysgit 1.8.1.2 -preview20130201.
I have also installed Git-1.8.3-preview20130601 in a separate directory.
No matter which of the two versions SmartGit uses, the problems persists.

The message given by SmartGit upon trying to save a stash is:

```
0 [main] us 0 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to us.stackdump
0 [main] sh.exe" 8776 sync_with_child: child 936(0x18C) died before initia
lization with status code 0xC0000005
85 [main] sh.exe" 8776 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp

C:\Program Files\SmartGitHg 4.5\git/libexec/git-core\git-stash: fork: Resource t
emporarily unavailable
```

Clean Up generates the following message:

```
Clean Up: failed to run repack
0 [main] us 0 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to us.stackdump
0 [main] sh.exe" 7236 sync_with_child: child 1236(0x988) died before
initialization with status code 0xC0000005
4811 [main] sh.exe" 7236 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
```

If I use the Git Gui directly (instead of SmartGit),to do the compression on the same repository, I get:

```
0 [main] sh.exe" 384 sync_with_child: child 7628(0x9A0) died before
initialization with status code 0xC0000005
1086 [main] sh.exe" 384 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If I try virtually anything with the Git Bash console, for example ls

```
sh.exe"-3.1$ ls
0 [main] us 0 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to us.stackdump
68591127 [main] sh.exe" 712 sync_with_child: child 4772(0x1B4) died before initi
alization with status code 0xC0000005
68591227 [main] sh.exe" 712 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp

sh.exe": fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
sh.exe"-3.1$
```

However, if I use Cygwin (git gc) on the repository, everything works fine.

I have done a web search and have found that other users have had similar error messages.  The closest I found was:

[Git sh.exe process forking issue on windows XP, slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851611/git-sh-exe-process-forking-issue-on-windows-xp-slow)

But I don't believe that I have the same issue.
Any suggestions on what I could try would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ivo

I have two computers running XP.  One of them runs Git-1.8.3-preview20130601 without problems, the other doesn't.  On the one that doesn't I started the machine in diagnostic startup -virtually no services running and I still have the same problem.  I suppose it could be something to do with the registry?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=190 may be related

Comment: Thanks Roger for the link.  I uninstalled Google desktop with no benefit.  I haven't had any breakthrough.  I probably did something really stupid - I copied sh.exe from cygwin to the \Git\bin directory and now it seems to work ok.  Also SmartGit now works well.  I will probably have some performance impact but at least its working.  Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I am having these issues on Windows 7 64-bit. Any new information would be wonderful.

Comment: I am getting this same thing on Windows 8 Pro 64-bit as well