# msysgit very slow in Windows 7

Tags: git, msysgit

I recently installed msysgit on my computer (Windows 7 SP1 64-bit). I downloaded [Git version 1.7.10](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.10-preview20120409.exe&can=2&q=) from [Google Code](http://code.google.com) and ran the installer. I chose 'Run Git from Windows Command Prompt' and then left the rest as default.

I then started a Command Prompt as Administrator and ran `git init` on a project folder to initialize the repository. The command took 48 seconds to complete. Running `git add *` or `git commit` take about the same. The project contains a few folders and files.

Is this normal? I was under the impression that git was faster than other DVCS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: git for windows is much slower then in linux.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775/msysgit-bash-is-horrendously-slow-in-windows-7 doesn't help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64 ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried all the above links plus a few others from other forums. I always used it in Linux but never thought there was going to be such a massive difference in speed between operating systems.

Comment: Have you rebooted?  I ran into a similar problem and rebooting after installing fixed it.

Comment: I just restarted my machine and the difference is massive. Running git init takes 2-3 seconds, git add * less than a second. Thanks! You should add it as the answer for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to restart Windows after installing msysgit. Thanks to Ryan Rinaldi for the help!

**Edit**: It hasn't happened again since I upgraded to version 1.8.0.msysgit.0