# msysgit: Prevent the Git bash from locking files of running shell scripts

Tags: shell, windows-7, file-io, msysgit, git-bash

I have some scripts that are (always) running during development. Trying to write to these files in Windows 7 fails (`git pull` fails with `Permission denied` error). Everything works fine in Linux.

1. Can I prevent Git bash from locking the files without changing my global [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) settings?
2. What other alternatives do I have (besides fixing/hacking the Git bash or Windows)?

Here is an example script as basis for the discussion:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "command + args: $0 $1 $2 $3"    
while sleep 2; do date +%s; done
```

I found a somehow related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2967519/8986). But unfortunately it did not provide a suitable solution, e.g., `Run as Administrator` does not help.

Another interesting observation is that I can still write the files when editing them in vim using `:w!` (forcing an overwrite).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run a copy of the file.

```
cp foo.sh /usr/local/bin
foo.sh
```

This would allow you to edit the file in the repo while the other is running. You could also try a hard link.

```
ln foo.sh /usr/local/bin
foo.sh
```