# Git-bash tab completion: "fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'" (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I'm using git on windows with the git bash and every time I want to autocomplete a filename in a git command I get `fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'` posted between my already typed characters and the completed ones.

It looks like this:

```
$ git diff a
<using tab>
$ git diff afatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
pp.js
```

I can still make the command properly by just pressing enter as expected. But it really starts to get on my nerves.

Any suggestions?

---

The problem was an extra `.git`-folder in my src folder. The repository was initialized on the folder above (`src/..`) and this seemed to mess with git. After the removal of the extra `.git` folder the problem disappered.

Comment: btw. other commands, like cd, work totally fine.

Comment: `git add` works fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discoverd the solution. I had an extra `.git` directory in my `src`-folder which seemed to mess with git (the repository was initialised on the folder above).

After I removed the extra `.git` folder the problem disappered.

Answer (score 2):

It can depends on the msysgit version you are using:

I just tested a tab completion on a git diff on W7 64bits, with the latest msysgit1.8.3, and it worked just fine.

Don't forget that, in addition to the msysgit version, you will have issues with tab completion due to the [old bash 3.1 included in mysysgit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/AgGY7wl8IJQ/arOX3-yQIqwJ).
And the [completion can be slow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775/msysgit-bash-is-horrendously-slow-in-windows-7).

---

As the [OP Zeeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274224/zeeker) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18060531/6309) below, the completion [`git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) is based on a [**proper git repo path detection**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L32-L34).

```
# __gitdir accepts 0 or 1 arguments (i.e., location)
# returns location of .git repo
__gitdir () {
...
}
```

And in Zeeker's case, **an extra `.git` folder was in the `src` folder**, which means any completion was based from the wrong folder, which, for [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L1171-L1189), proved fatal.
[`git add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L892-L905) seems to work though.

Comment: +1.  IIRC, completion has undergone several fixes.  I would not be surprised if a release made it out with some brokeness.

Comment: I just installed the newest version of msysgit but still have the problem. Is there any way to manually install a new bash version?

Comment: @Zeeker not that I know of. What Windows OS version are you using?

Comment: Im using Windows 7 64bits.

Comment: @Zeeker Strange. Me too. Does the issue persist if you install a portable version of msysgit (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) somewhere else on your computer?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists.

Comment: @Zeeker What is the value of your `$HOME` in that gitbash session? And is there any `.bashrc` or `.profile` file in that directory referenced by `$HOME`?

Comment: The `$HOME` variable is pointing to my home directory (`C:\Users\<username>`). I have a `.profile` file, but this isn't the cause of the problem. I already tried a session without the file but it didn't fix it.

Comment: @Zeeker And what about setting your HOME (temporarily, in the current bash session) to another folder? Would that change anything? I do assume you are using the latest msygit 1.8.3, right?

Comment: I discovered a solution. I will answer it on a seperate comment.

Comment: @Zeeker I will include it in my answer for more visiblity

Answer (score 0):

git-bash completion for git commands is controlled by the /etc/git-completion.bash.  To fix run git-bash as administrator, then:

```
cd /etc
mv /etc/git-completion.bash /etc/git-completion.bash.orig
```

Then create a new one from the contents of https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But sadly this didn't fix the issue.