# Git stops working, sh.exe moved

Tags: git, antivirus

After I install git it works fine, sometimes I have to pause the antivirus to install properly.  But after a while it stops working and when trying to commit something the CMD says :'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. And I have to install git again. Also when I try to open git bash I get a message saying sh.exe has been changed or moved.  I do not want to install it everitime I need it how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `%PATH%` still references `<path/to/git>/bin`, it is possible that the anti-virus would automatically remove the `git.exe`.

One way is to add the git installation path to the whitelist of said anti-virus, in order to not be monitored and left alone.
Plus, the [real-time scanning can have an effect on git speed as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172824/6309).