# Why is git slow on my windows machine?

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, posh-git

Just typing `git` at the command prompt (of powershell), takes 2.5 seconds until it returns with the help message.

I'm using the git for windows release, installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`. When I use cygwin (via babun), I get an error: `Hint: your prompt is very slow. Check the installed 'BLODA' software.` Maybe this is related? If it is, I'm using a corporate laptop, so can't uninstall antivirus or driver software, are there other options?

Comment: Look into garbage collection.

Comment: If you run git from powershell it will have start the whole MSYS environment each time. Check to see if it runs faster from git bash.

Comment: Didn't want to suggest a duplicate yet, but these are similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775/msysgit-bash-is-horrendously-slow-in-windows-7

Comment: And also here: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow

Comment: For Windows 10 users, sufficient explanations and solutions in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888024/git-bash-mintty-is-extremely-slow-on-windows-10-os/70192846

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the reason seemed to be the "Inject ConEmuHk" setting in cmder under which I ran git. I've opened a bug https://github.com/bliker/cmder/issues/592

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if the issue persists with the [latest 2.4+ git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).

There is a [bug related to the git bash startup time](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/193) which is actively addressed.

Comment: Same. Outside of a repository performance looks OK, but once I cd to a repository folder it is slow (2 seconds to return)

Comment: @IttayD Ok. I guess the bug is still pending then.